# Logic Pro X / Mastering / Volume / Soundcloud

Tags: mixing, mastering, logic

Ok hope someone can help. I listen to other peoples mixes / masters and the sound levels are all nice and loud, I do my own and they are nowhere near loud enough. I have tried all sorts, compressors, limters, no effects, final effects nothing works. I mix everthing as loud as possible without distortions and without destroying the mix and still its not as loud as other peoples. Even some of my own mixes volumes are vastly different but still none are as loud as other peoples. Anyone any ideas? go to my soundcloud, search for Northern Gear, have a listen and you will see what i mean and compare to others. Ta Mucho

Comment: Stumbled across this today and remembered this post, might be a useful read for you https://www.soundonsound.com/techniques/crafting-loud-mixes-sound-great

Answer (score 4):

"I mix everything as loud as possible". There is your problem. Right there.

Mixing music is not about making it "loud". If you think it is, you are focussing on the wrong thing entirely.

There are any number of resources available to you to learn how to mix - too many to list here.

One tip I will give you is to focus on spectral balance and dynamic range. Use a "loudness" metering plugin and start by mixing to a consistent loudness using the metering as a guide.

Comment: This. When you overly compress music to make it "louder", it actually starts to sound more quiet after a certain point. Also, modern digital music services are asking for music to have much **less** compression on the overall track, and they will take care of evening out the loudness. Sending a dynamic master to streaming services like Spotify will help make your mix sound louder than sending something that has been compressed.